# Is it possible to define GET and POST like this?

Tags: php

I want to change the request method according to variable, like in the example:

```
$input = "GET me out of here!";
$method = strtoupper($input != "It should be POST" ? "get" : "post");
$exists = isset($_${$method}["some-variable"]) && $_${$method}["some-variable"] == "I can be both get and post!";
```

Is it possible / valid?

Comment: I tried it now, and seems like it won't work this way. I'm not sure if it can work anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `$method = '_POST';` and then do `$$method` to access `$_POST`:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/45381e507fe957cabb751e4bd62a71418a7bb45f

```
$input = "GET me out of here!";
$_GET = ["some-variable" => "I can be both get and post!"];
$method = strtoupper($input != "It should be POST" ? "_GET" : "_POST");
$exists = isset($$method["some-variable"]) && $$method["some-variable"] == "I can be both get and post!";
echo $exists ? "exists" : "nope";  // exists
```

That being said, you could also just use `$_REQUEST` with the caveat that it also includes `$_COOKIE`